# Guardar imagen en variable

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo este código para agregar una imagen a un `JLabel`:

```
    public void Cargar_Imagen() { 
    File fichero;
    int resultado;
    VentanaImg_Contacto vi= new VentanaImg_Contacto();

    FileNameExtensionFilter filtro=
            new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPG y PNG", "jpg", "png");

    vi.jfchCargarFoto.setFileFilter(filtro);
    resultado= vi.jfchCargarFoto.showOpenDialog(null);

    if(JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION== resultado)
    {
        fichero= vi.jfchCargarFoto.getSelectedFile();

        try {
            ImageIcon icon= new ImageIcon(fichero.toString());
            Icon icono= new ImageIcon(icon.getImage().
                    getScaledInstance(VentanaAgr_Contacto1.lblFoto.getWidth(),
                            VentanaAgr_Contacto1.lblFoto.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al abrir la imagen "+e);
        }
    }else if(JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION == null ? Integer.toString(resultado) == null : JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION.equals(Integer.toString(resultado)))
        {
            VentanaImg_Contacto.jfchCargarFoto.setVisible(false);
        }
}
```

Quisiera saber cómo puedo hacer para cuando presione un botón la imagen seleccionada, se guarde en una variable privada de otra clase donde tengo este código:

```
    public void Guardar(){
            arreglo.add(new Controlador.Contacto(
            // Aquí debería poner el nombre del JLabel junto con setIcon no es compatible,
            txt_Nombre.getText(), txt_Apellido.getText(), 
            Integer.parseInt(txt_Movil.getText()),
            Integer.parseInt(txt_Casa.getText())));
    }
```

Comment: Cambia el alcance de la variable `Icon icono` de ser una variable local al método a que sea una variable para tu ventana.

Comment: Lo estoy haciendo mediante MVC no tengo el código dentro de la ventana

Comment: Me refiero a que la variable esté declarada como atributo de la clase que maneja las acciones de tu ventana, mejor dicho que la variable sea parte del controller, así como tienes tus variables `VentanaAgr_Contacto1.lblFoto` y otras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eso lo mas comun es el de convertir la imagen a bits para guardarla en una variable de ese tipo y volverla a construir para poder entender mejor esa opción anexo un video donde te explican como guardar la imagen mas aparte un texto relacionado a esa imagen:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HeHLvUaZolU

Comment: Gracias @JoseRubenAlejandro algo como eso era lo que buscaba

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente, cambia el ámbito de tu variable `icono` a un ambito global dentro de tu clase, por ejemplo:

```
public class MiClase {
    private Icon icono;

    //demas variables y metodos de la clase
}
```

recuerda entonces dejar en tu metodo que carga la imagen la inicialización de la variable `icono`

```
icono= new ImageIcon(icon.getImage()....
```

En esa misma clase supongo que debes tener una instancia de alguna clase que implemente `ActionListener`, para que al ejecutar el botón; ejecutes una acción determinada.

Como ya tienes la variable `icono` inicializada (tomate el tiempo de validar esto para evitar posibles `NullPointerException`) puedes pasarla como argumento a tu otra clase, bien por argumento del mismo método guardar o por constructor de tu otra clase.

Por argumento de tu método guardar:

```
public class MiClase {
    private MiOtraClase otra;

    //inicializas la variable icono
    icono = .....

    //la pasas como argumento de metodo a otra clase
    otra.guardar(icono);

   //o por constructor
   otra = new MiOtraClase(icono);
}
```

Es necesario que en tu "otra clase" definas tu constructor o tu método de acuerdo a como lo vas a almacenar

```
//constructor
private Icon icono;

public MiOtraClase(Icon icono) {
    this.icono = icono;
}
```

Otro tema importante JAVA atiende al estilo de escritura [CamelCase](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), en tu código hay variables y nombres de métodos que no cumplen con ello, en lugar de `VentanaImg_Contacto` debes usar `VentanaImgContacto` si es que es una clase o `ventanaImgContacto` si es que es una variable o un nombre de método. Los nombres de métodos no inician con mayúscula, se escriben en lowerCamelCase.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por los consejos @RosendoRopher, permíteme decirte que para esto estoy utilizando el patrón de desarrollo DAO por tanto, no tengo ninguna clase que implemente ActionListener

Comment: Según los tags de tu pregunta estas usando swing, en algún lado de tu aplicación debes estar implementando un ActionListener asi sea en un inner class, de otra manera tus botones o componentes no responderían a eventos. DAO se refiere a la capa que existe entre tu logica de negocio y tu capa de persistencia. Saludos.

Comment: Si, en eso tienes razón, pero no lo implemento en esa clase como muy bien lo dijiste, disculpa mis conocimientos de Java no son tan avanzados

Comment: La idea es que en ese evento (cuando presiones el boton) pases tu icono como argumento a la otra clase, tal como menciono en la respuesta. Si te queda alguna duda, a la orden!

Comment: Hay alguna posibilidad de iniciar un chat @RosendoRopher

Comment: Que tal, necesitas el chat aun? He visto que se activa la opción al pasar determinada cantidad de comentarios.

Comment: No lo sabía, pero sí. necesito una ayuda con unas cuantas cosas

Comment: Ya con esta cantidad de comentarios debería activarse la opción de chat.

Comment: Esperemos a ver